# What are the advantages and disadvantages of serving JSON data as text/javascript compared to the official standard: application/json?

Tags: javascript, html, json, mime-types

What are the advantages and disadvantages of serving JSON data as `text/javascript` to a **web browser** compared to the [official standard: application/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) ?

I'm only asking this question because facebook is returning JSON data as `text/javascript` instead of the official standard `application/json` ([example](https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552), [example](https://graph.facebook.com/1929286855212), [example](https://graph.facebook.com/1929286855)) and i would like to know what may be the reason behind this decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in some other question, returning JSON with a `text` MIME type is neccessary if you want to upload files using the HTML4 method: submit your upload form to an iframe, and get the JSON response by extracting the iframe's innerHTML.

With MIME type `application/json`, browsers will offer to save the JSON instead of displaying it.

Personally, I always use `text/plain`, there is no disadvantage.

Comment: so what's the advantage then for using text/plain when i do not require the iframe trick?

Comment: You won't have to change your server configuration if you decide to implement uploads one day. Not a big deal for a small website, but for Facebook it sure is.

Comment: since there isn't a better provided ans i'd do with this

Answer (score 1):

A mime type application would force the browser to save it to disk. Maybe Facebook doesn't want this? But I don't see an advantage or disadvantage.

Answer (score 1):

I would say in general, there is no advantage/disadvantage.  If you were downloading the code, maybe the browser might try to interpret the mime type.  Or if you are building an application using the mime types and want to handle it a certain way.

For purposes of facebook is doing, there wouldn't be any advant/disadvant